# onMouseDown effect on button

Tags: c#, html, css, button

So, I was trying to use CSS which will give the onMouseDown impression of the button when it is disabled, to allow the user to know it is disabled, visually.

not sure what to put inside .disableApproveButton was looking for mouse down and stuff....any ideas?
thanks

```
<td><button class="disableApproveButton" type="submit" name="btnApprove" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.Email) ? "disabled" : string.Empty)>Approve</button></td>

.disableApproveButton 
{
 //make selection here
}
```

Comment: So, you just want to make it look like disabled?

Comment: yea, it is actually disabled as it does nothing, but i would like the visual effect of it, as the user can still click the button and it flashes

Comment: Can you share your regular button style? And, how do you disable it? Because, disabling it will make it look like disabled.

Comment: <button type="submit" name="btnApprove" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.Email) ? "disabled" : string.Empty)>Approve</button>

Comment: thats my button if the condition is true it navigates the user, if the condition is false it does nothing...but can still be clicked ??

Comment: This question is a bit off topic. If you have a style in mind but are not able to achieve how it looks we can help! However without any starting ground there's not much we can do.

Comment: @Don, I don't think the button is being disabled at all. I think it is because John is using "disabled" (in quotes) rather than the property of the object: disabled.

Comment: @brainwipe I see, I thought he was styling his buttons asking for a custom style for disabled buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add  disabled attribute to you button/submit type.

```
<button type="submit" name="btnApprove" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.Email) ? disabled : string.Empty)>Approve</button>
```

You might have to change the code based on your logic, but the point is you must utilize disabled attribute of a button.

JsFiddle Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7AzFV/1/